# Assigning retrieved data from a database to a string variable

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a system that is meant to validate credentials already defined in the database with those entered in the jTextfield. When I enter the condition in the if-else statement it says cannot String cannot be converted to boolean. Please help.

```
 Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection (host, uName, uPass);
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement ();
        //login is a table in my database,password a tuple
        String SQL = "SELECT password FROM login;";
        ResultSet password = stmt.executeQuery (SQL);

        String pass = adminpassword.getText();
        String sqlpass = password.getString("password");
//error shows on if else below
        if(sqlpass = pass){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have entered an incorrect password,please try again.","Incorrect Password",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        else{
            String passconfirm = "SELECT admin_id WHERE password = 77353";
            ResultSet confirmpass = stmt.executeQuery(passconfirm);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome","Welcome " + confirmpass,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Countyinfo proceed = new Countyinfo();
            proceed.setVisible(true);
        }
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
         System.out.println (err.getMessage());
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The boolean operator for equality is `==`, not `=` (which is the assignment operator). An assignment operation will always evaluate to the value assigned to its left value.

That's why `sqlpass = pass` evaluates to a `String`.
`sqlpass == pass` will evaluate to a `boolean`.

EDIT:
Still, the standard way to compare `String`s is using the `.equals` method like this:

`if(sqlpass.equals(pass))`

Comment: Why you not using .equals() method to compare String object.

Comment: Definitely, `.equals` is the right way to compare `String`s. I focused so much on the difference between assignment and equality operators, that I missed the point.

Answer (score 1):

You have an assignment in your `if` statement expression which returns a `String` rather than the required `boolean`.

```
if (sqlpass = pass) {
```

should be

```
if (sqlpass.equals(pass)) {
```

to compare `Strings` (the `==` operator compares `Object` references rather than content)